# How can I add terminal console messages in mochawesome report

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate accessibility  testing using cypress-axe .I want to add the terminal console messages to my mochaweome report.

Comment: Can you also add the code you tried along with screenshots of error if you faced any ?

Comment: This question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702340/how-to-view-cy-log-output-in-mochawesome-html-report