# How to view cy.log() output in mochawesome HTML report

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, mochawesome

I want to view the output of cy.log() command in mochawesome HTML report. Below is the code

```
    /// <reference types="cypress" />

describe("Cypress File Upload", function() {
    it("File Upload test", () => {
        cy.visit('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/')
        cy.get('a[href="/upload"]').click()
        const file = 'example.json'
        cy.get('#file-upload').click().attachFile(file)
        cy.get('#file-submit').click()
        cy.log(file)
        cy.get('#uploaded-files').contains('example.json', {matchCase: true})
    })
})
```

The generated HTML report shows cy.log(file) as it is although example.json is expected[image]
How can I view the output of aforementioned command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *addContext*. In *cypress/support/commands.js* you have to put this code:

```
import addContext from 'mochawesome/addContext';
Cypress.Commands.add('addContext', (context) => {
  cy.once('test:after:run', (test) => addContext({ test }, context));
});
```

After that you can use the command *cy.adContext* in your test:

```
cy.get('p').invoke('text').then(($text) => {
  cy.addContext($text);
});
```